# Add multiple key value pairs in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

I want a JavaScript object which should have multiple key values pairs. However, I am unable to add.
On clicking a function, I am getting multiple key value pairs as

```
{id:"1" ,desc: "first"} , {id:"2", desc:"two"} , {id:"3" , desc:"three"} ...
```

How can I add them to the object so that the final object should look like this:

```
prdObj= ({id:"1" ,desc: "first"} , {id:"2", desc:"two"} , {id:"3" , desc:"three"});
```

Comment: You need to store it in an array. But you need to share your code to get help that solves your problem.

Comment: Is your final output array of objects? Or you need a single object with those key and values? Your question is unclear on this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
prdObj = [{id:"1" ,desc: "first"} , {id:"2", desc:"two"} , {id:"3" , desc:"three"}];

//when adding
prdObj.push( {id:"4" , desc:"four"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with single key value:

`var yourObject = [{"yourkey":"yourvalue"}, {"yourkey":"yourvalue"}];`

OR

`var yourObject = [{"key1":"yourvalue", "key2":"yourvalue"}, {"key1":"yourvalue", "key2":"yourvalue"}];`